# building web-scraper, i havetargeted the container, but trouble getting ID of tweet

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hey i am trying to build a twitterweb scraper with `bs4` in `python`. 
It works really well, but i have just found that i need to also the scrape the id of the tweets that i am scraping

[image]

in the picture of the html that i have submitted, i have been able to target the container "div"{"class":"tweet"} with this code:

[image]

i cant seem to get the code to retrieve the "data-item-id". does anyone have a tip on how to to get it?
thanks a lot

Comment: please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html rather than post images. Code should be posted between code tags (paste code in, highlight it and press Ctrl+K)

Comment: oh yeah thx, i will make sure to do that another time

Comment: hmmm.... its giving me trouble whenever i try to

Comment: What do you mean by trouble?

Comment: problems with indentation whenever i try to use the code snippet function

Comment: Have you html already formatted then paste in top left box of snippet tool and press save and insert button

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attributes as variables after you select using soup.find.

> soup.find('div',{'class':'tweet'})['data-tweet-id']

This would select the first div with the class tweet and having the data-tweet-id attribute.

Comment: hmmm... it seems to return Nonetype

Comment: just to be certain, is the thing i am loking for css? or what is it called

Comment: Yes, I was trying to solve it using css selectors at first and ended up eyeballing it because I had no access to the code.